# Pull Google Plus insights data for multiple pages into excel

Tags: google-plus

I have been all over the web looking for a way to pull all the insights data from all my Google Plus pages into excel.  Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I have been hunting for something to do this for some time now. After months of digging between projects, I found a way. This utility has been EXTREMELY helpful with this task and in fact, it goes above and beyond giving you the ability to pull in all social media info and GA data. Simply AMAZING. If you would like to pull in your data, check out [NextAnalytics](http://www.nextanalytics.com/).